# The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer. Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, widget

Heelo Community i am doing a liquid swipe screen. the app has 4 Containers, with a page index.
on the last container i added a button that when onpressed: (){ Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);} for some Reasons the my codes complains about the context.

Things i Tried---->
I tried creating a

```
 setState(() {
      if(isSelected == true){
        print("Selected is true2");
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
        displayToastMessage("you are logged-in now.", context);
      }
```

Then in my MaterialButton onPressed I had:

```
Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 40),
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () => {

                      isSelected = true,

                      if(isSelected == true){
                        print("Selected is true1")
                      }
                    },

                    fillColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    splashColor: Colors.blue,

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Accept EULA",
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
```

But when i run the program the button it doesn't work

All i want to do is to Navigate to the main screen when the MaterialRawButton is pressed

Here is my code:

```
class InformationScreens extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String idScreen = "informationScreen";
  
  @override
  _WithPages createState() => _WithPages();
}

class _WithPages extends State<InformationScreens> {

  int page = 0;
  LiquidController liquidController;
  UpdateType updateType;


  @override
  void initState() {
    liquidController = LiquidController();
    super.initState();

  }

  final pages = [
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 20),
              height: 600,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(
                  ''' this is some text'''
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 40),
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () => {

  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
  displayToastMessage("you are logged-in now.", context);
                    },

                    fillColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    splashColor: Colors.blue,

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Accept EULA",
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ];


  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    double selectedness = Curves.easeOut.transform(
      max(
        0.0,
        1.0 - ((page ?? 0) - index).abs(),
      ),
    );
    
    double zoom = 1.0 + (2.0 - 1.0) * selectedness;
    return new Container(
      width: 25.0,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Material(

          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          child: new Container(
            width: 8.0 * zoom,
            height: 8.0 * zoom,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            LiquidSwipe(
              pages: pages,
              positionSlideIcon: 0.8,
              slideIconWidget: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              onPageChangeCallback: pageChangeCallback,
              waveType: WaveType.liquidReveal,
              liquidController: liquidController,
              ignoreUserGestureWhileAnimating: true,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(pages.length, _buildDot),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    liquidController.animateToPage(
                        page: pages.length - 1, duration: 700);
                  },
                  child: Text("Skip to End"),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.01),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    liquidController.jumpToPage(page: liquidController.currentPage + 1 > 
                    pages.length - 1
                                ? 0
                                : liquidController.currentPage + 1);
                  },

                  child: Text("Next"),
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.01),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );


  }
  pageChangeCallback(int lpage) {
    setState(() {
      page = lpage;

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store widgets in variables unless you know what you're doing. It's just going to create more issues that you won't understand. Either make them methods like the `_buildDot` method you have, or insert it directly in `build`.

Example with getter method:

```dart
List<Widget> get pages => [
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(),
    Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 20),
              height: 600,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Text(
                  ''' this is some text'''
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 40),
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () => {

  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, MainScreen.idScreen, (route) => false);
  displayToastMessage("you are logged-in now.", context);
                    },

                    fillColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                    splashColor: Colors.blue,

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: const <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Accept EULA",
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_forward,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ];
```

Comment: Lol, Thanks for the response: I am using the liquid Swipe code with Item Builder: Here is the link: https://github.com/iamSahdeep/liquid_swipe_flutter/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: Pls try to understand what i am trying to do

Comment: @BankySam It's unclear how you expect me to respond. Did this not solve you error?

Comment: thanks i tried it, It worked just want to know why it worked, tho i had to remove the double, so that it doesn't return anything. And also how to get better at flutter